# Pull data from two tables and provide all data elements

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have one table that I created with Names, SSN, and dates.  I want to look inside another table and still pull all the info from my first table, but also if the name is found in the second table, provide that data.  If not, provide a Null Value.  I believe this is a left join, but may be mistaken.

This is my code:

```
if object_id('tempdb..#ssns') is not null drop table #ssns 
create table #ssns
  (ssnId int, fName varchar(50), ssn varchar(20), ReqDate datetime2(0))
insert into #ssns values (1,'test,test','0001','20180621'),

if object_id('tempdb..#pt') is not null drop table #pt 
select a.*, b.patientSID, b.patientName, b.patientSSN, b.DeathDateTime

into #pt    
from #ssns a
join spatient.spatient b on b.patientname = a.fname 
where b.sta3n = 558 and RIGHT(b.patientSSN,4) = a.ssn

if object_id('tempdb..#ptappt') is not null drop table #ptappt
select a.*, c.locationName, d.stopCode, b.appointmentDateTime,  b.appointmentStatus

into #ptappt
from #pt a
left join LSV.D01_VISN06.cci_Appt_Appointment b on b.patientSID = a.patientSID and b.sta3n = 558
join dim.location c on c.locationSID = b.locationSID and c.sta3n = 558
join dim.stopCode d on d.stopCodeSID = c.primaryStopCodeSID and d.sta3n = 558

where isnull(b.AppointmentStatus,'Null') not in ('C', 'CA') 
and appointmentDateTime >= a.reqDate
and d.stopCode in ('323', '322', '350')
```

Comment: Is there a reason your code doesn't have a `select`?  And what database are you using?  Your question mentions two tables, your query has 4 tables.  Sample data, desired results, and a clear question would really help.

Comment: My first table pulls 371 line items.  When I do a left or right join, it only comes back with 13 with the responses only pulling data that is found in the second table.  I would like my output to pull 384 = 371+13 or there about.

Comment: Yes, I didn't add the select because I didn't think that was really necessary.  I am just trying to get it to gather all the data from the second table.  The items in the third and fourth table will always have data from the first table.  A clinic is not created without giving a stopCode or a locationName.

Comment: I am using a T-SQL company DataBase.  I don't know if this answers your database question.

Comment: . . As the author of the question, you can edit it to clarify points that might need clarifying.

Comment: Thank you.  I have updated my code to provide what I have so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer. You filter the where clause on the join:

```
from #pt a
left join LSV.D01_VISN06.cci_Appt_Appointment b on b.patientSID = a.patientSID and   b.sta3n = 558 and 
isnull(b.AppointmentStatus,'Null') not in ('C', 'CA') 
and appointmentDateTime >= a.reqDate
left join dim.location c on c.locationSID = b.locationSID and c.sta3n = 558
left join dim.stopCode d on d.stopCodeSID = c.primaryStopCodeSID and d.sta3n = 558
and d.stopCode in ('323', '322', '350')
```